# examples of how to write beautiful c++ comments

Tags: c++, comments

maybe is stupid question but is there any way to write good looking (short ) format 
to write comments for c++ function,headers,variable ? any visual examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by good looking here ?
I do it like this ..

```
int c;//! loop Counter

/**
 * compares (XOR) two Types
 * return boolean result
 */
bool compare(Type l, Type r);
```

Its doxygen format. there are populer formats for documenting codes in Comment. Doxygen is one and another one is naturaldocs. there are even more. Its your flavour. You may even like the naturaldocs format.

```
/*
   Function: Compare
   Compares two Types
   Parameters:
      l - lhs
      r - rhs.
   Returns:
      boolean result

*/
bool compare(Type l, Type r);
```

The DOC++ format is also similer like.

```
/** Comparison
    Compare two Types

    @param l Type lhs
    @param r Type rhs
    @return boolean result
*/
bool compare(Type l, Type r);
```

Just use only one format and stick with it.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using this style:

```
/**
 * Class name
 * Description
 */

class MyClass{

}
```

Comment: +1, I prefer this comment, it's very typical with eclipse.

Comment: Isn't this `/**` an indicator for [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/)?

Comment: Can't say, I'm not aware of it =). but this is the style I liked the most. It's simple and very nice looking.

Comment: Ya This is Doxygen Style

Answer (score 2):

Some would suggest that the most beautiful comments are those which are consistent throughout a program. I prefer to use forward slashes:

```
// -- short concise comments in single lines like this

// -----------------------------------------
//
//    Sectional Dividers Like This
//
// -----------------------------------------
```

That said, these won't help if you are hoping to generate documentation from your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do it in such a way that some automated tool can extract them and create cross linked documentation. Have a look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Answer (score 1):

I use following style:

for method:

```
/**
 * Method description.
 * @param param1 param1 description 
 * @param param2 param2 description
 * @return return description
 * @since date since method is created
 * @author who have made this method.
 */
```

for variables:

```
/** variables description **/
```

for class:

```
/**
 * Class description.
 * @since date since class is created
 * @author who have made this class.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [http://www.doxygen.nl/](http://www.doxygen.nl).  Basically, a take-off on the JavaDoc format, where the format is interpreted, to a certain degree, for a help file.

I'm a believer in self-documenting code, but a few well-versed comments can help a lot.